# I'm having trouble viewing my VB.net debug build

Tags: vb.net

I've started making an application in Visual Studios using VB.net and as i've been trying to run it a few issues have come up. My application in the practice builds is unmovable on the screen and unclosable. Also the screen is very fuzzy and all the objects have lines going through them. Please let me know if you have any solutions.

[image]

```
Public Class AWPvbFin 

End Class
```

Comment: You are pushing the Start button on the tool bar and that is what you see. Yes?

Comment: Is this the first form in the program, the start up form? Is there any code in the Form_Load event or Form_Loaded event?

Comment: Hey Mary, this is the first form in the program and is the start up form. I am also pushing the start button and this is what is being shown. The code I have in form1.vb is  Public Class AWPvbFin                    End Class (I can't figure out how to return on stack overflow with out submitting this comment so pretend that tab is a new line)

Comment: Please show your code. It seems that something may be blocking the UI thread.

Comment: Please edit your question, and include the code of form1.vb and form1.designer.vb

Comment: Open Solution Explorer (in VS menu: View => Solution Explorer). Then click the arrow next to `AWPvbFin.vb` to expand it. Then click the arrow next to `AWPvbFin` to expand it. Double-click `Dispose(Boolean)`. Post the code that is shown.